# Looking for a timetable diagram

Tags: diagrams

How can I archieve a diagram like below?

[image]

Comment: Hi and Welcome, looks like a bar plot to me. Please have a look at `pgfplots`.

Comment: By the way, if you are looking for help in german, check out [TeXwelt.de](http://texwelt.de/wissen/).

Comment: Do you want to do these kinds of diagram repeatedly, or just one?

Comment: Why wasn't my drawing good enough anymore? `:(` You haven't given a `tikz` tag or anything.

Comment: I'm sorry, but pstricks doesn't work with the pdflatex settings, so I prefered the tikz solution instead of pstricks.
Here is the error message: 
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps 
                             
l.10   \psline{->}
                  (1.8,0.42)(7.7,0.42)

Comment: @DerStephanAusBerlin Just compile with the `-shell-escape` option. If you still want the TikZ solution, you should write it in the question.

Comment: @Svend Tveskæg: Don't know how to do this, cause I am using MikTex for Windows here.
Do you have a hint?

Comment: What has that got to do with things? It depends on your editor and nothing else. (You have to compile using `pdflatex -shell-escape file-name.tex`.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg As a Windows user he might not use the command line to compile, so it could be quite a problem trying to find how to add the compile option. Many Windows users expect their stuff to just work and when they do they usually never to bother looking for options - so since the tikz solution seems to compile without trying to locate and change the compile command in the editor's option menu - he seems to prefer it - but maybe I am just projecting....

Comment: I bet google works nevertheless. [Wie aktiviere ich -shell-escape in meinem Editor?](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/10341/wie-aktiviere-ich-shell-escape-in-meinem-editor)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `tikz` solution.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x/\l in {0/0,1/10,2/20,3/30,4/40,5/50}{
  \foreach \y/\ll in {0/Network,1/Disk,2/CPU}{
  \draw[->] (-0.5,\y)node[left=2cm, anchor=west]{\ll} -- (6,\y);}
  \draw[dashed] (\x,0)node[below]{\l}--(\x,2);
  }
  \node[below] at(6,0){[\textup{ms}]};
  \draw[line width=3pt] (1,2)--(3,2);
  \draw[line width=3pt] (0,1)--(1,1);
  \draw[line width=3pt] (3,0)--(4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `[ms]` --> `[\textup{ms}]`

Answer (score 5):

A PSTtricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\def\timeline(#1)#2{%
  \psline{->}(!1.8 #1 0.52 sub)(!7.7 #1 0.52 sub)
  \rput[l](!0 #1 0.52 sub){#2}}
\def\timeInterval(#1,#2)#3{%
  \psline[linewidth = 3pt](!#1 2 add #2 0.52 sub)(!#1 #3 add 2 add #2 0.52 sub)}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(8,2.6)
  % top
  \timeline(3){CPU}
  \timeInterval(1,3){2}
  % middle
  \timeline(2){Disk}
  \timeInterval(0,2){1}
  % bottom
  \timeline(1){Network}
  \timeInterval(3,1){1}
  % time labels
  \multido{\r = 2+1, \i = 0+10}{6}{%
    \rput(\r,0.17){$\i$}
    \psline[linestyle = dotted, dotsep = 2pt](\r,0.48)(\r,2.48)}
  \rput(7.7,0.18){[\si{\ms}]}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: `s/CUP/CPU/` perhaps?

Comment: @Thruston Maybe but I don't understand what you mean, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, I was using VIM syntax to suggest a change!  In the notation you used above: `CUP` --> `CPU`.  OK?!